# Как исправить ошибку компиляции: method in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

Проверка класса `Praktikum`.

Ошибка компиляции:

```
>/sandbox/tmp/Praktikum.java:46: error: method addRainyDay in class WeatherCalendar cannot be applied to given types;
                calendar.addRainyDay(rainyDays);
                        ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Failed compilation
```

Код:

```java
public class Praktikum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        
        WeatherCalendar calendar = new WeatherCalendar("Октябрь", 31);
        String[] octoberWeather = new String[] {
                "Солнечно",
                "Дождь",
                "Пасмурно",
                "Дождь",
                "Дождь",
                "Облачно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Дождь",
                "Пасмурно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Облачно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Дождь",
                "Пасмурно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Облачно",
                "Облачно",
                "Облачно",
                "Облачно",
                "Дождь",
                "Дождь",
                "Облачно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Дождь",
                "Пасмурно",
                "Дождь",
                "Солнечно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Солнечно",
                "Облачно"
        };
        int rainyDays = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < calendar.numberOfDays; i++) {
            if (octoberWeather[i].equals("Дождь")) {
                calendar.addRainyDay(rainyDays);
            }
        }

        // Проверить, был ли месяц дождливым. Если да - установить значение isRainyMonth
        if (calendar.rainyDays > 15) {
            calendar.isRainyMonth = true;
        }

        System.out.println(calendar.month + " " + calendar.year + " года. "
                + calendar.rainyDays + " дней шёл дождь.");

        // Проверить значение isRainyMonth
        if (calendar.isRainyMonth) {
            System.out.println("Это был дождливый месяц.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Этот месяц был довольно сухим.");
        }
    }
}
```

```java
class WeatherCalendar {
    String month;
    int numberOfDays;

    int rainyDays;
    boolean isRainyMonth = false;
    int year = 2020;

    public void  addRainyDay(int rainyDays) {
        this.rainyDays + 1;
    }
    public  WeatherCalendar(String monthName, int monthNumberOfDays) {
        month = monthName;
        numberOfDays = monthNumberOfDays;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В представленном коде НЕТ указанной ошибки компиляции о том, что в классе `WeatherCalendar` отсутствует метод с требуемым количеством аргументов.

Однако, он содержит *другую* ошибку компиляции в классе `WeatherCalendar`:

```
 error: not a statement
        this.rainyDays + 1;
                       ^
1 error
```

```java
    public void  addRainyDay(int rainyDays) {
        this.rainyDays + 1; // error: not a statement
    }
```

Фактически, этот код не имеет смысла, так как счётчик дождливых дней НЕ инкрементируется (результат операции *сложения* никуда не присваивается).
Следует либо использовать оператор присваивания (обычный `=` или сокращённый `+=`), либо какой-то из видов инкремента `++`.

Кроме того, параметр `rainyDays` НЕ используется в указанном методе `addRainyDay`, а значит, его можно убрать из объявления метода, изменив соответственно код вызова.

Таким образом, корректная реализация метода может выглядеть так (закомментированы эквивалентные варианты).

```java
// class WeatherCalendar
public void addRainyDay() {              // убрали ненужный параметр
    this.rainyDays++;                    // пост-инкремент
//  ++this.rainyDays;                    // пре-инкремент
//  this.rainyDays += 1;                 // сокращенное сложение
//  this.rainyDays = this.rainyDays + 1; // полное сложение
}
```

---

Соответственно, не нужно передавать параметр в данный метод, а значит, переменная `rainyDays` в методе `main` НЕ нужна.

```java
// class Praktikum, method main
        // убрали переменную `rainyDays`
        for (int i = 0; i < calendar.numberOfDays; i++) {
            if ("Дождь".equals(octoberWeather[i])) {
                calendar.addRainyDay();  // убрали ненужный параметр
            }
        }
```

Тогда в результате выполнения получится:

```
Октябрь 2020 года. 9 дней шёл дождь.
Этот месяц был довольно сухим.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка компиляции в том, что если вызывать метод `addRainyDay` с параметром, то в классе `WetherCalendar` должен быть определен метод с такой сигнатурой, т.е. таким именем, количеством аргументов, и их типами.

```
 public void  addRainyDay(int rainyDays)
```

Похоже, что во время компиляции такого метода не было, а был определен метод без аргументов.

```
 public void  addRainyDay()
```

Ошибка возникла, потому что был добавлен аргумент в метод `addRainyDay` с типом `int`. Потом поменялся вызов этого метода на

```
calendar.addRainyDay(rainyDays);
```

Теперь нужно вернутся назад и подумать: зачем нужен этот метод в классе, можно ли обойтись без него, нужен ли этому методу аргумент, что передавать в качестве аргумента.

Возможно класс `WetherCalendar` нужно изменить так, чтобы он содержал не только количество дождливых дней, но и информацию о том, какие дни месяца были дождливыми. Тогда в качестве параметра нужно передавать день месяца.

```
calendar.addRainyDay(i);
```

Тогда дождливые дни будут храниться в отдельном массиве или списке и количество таких дней можно вычислить

```
int[] rainyDays;

public int rainyDays() {
  int rainyDays = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
      if (this.rainyDays[i] > 0) {
         rainyDays++;
      }
  }

  return rainyDays;
}
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.